# How to avoid callback hell after one AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, asynchronous

I have a nodeJS application that requests data from an API once. I then want to do some processing on this data by using separate functions. However, since the AJAX is asynchronous, I'm forced to use async as follows:

```
async.series(
[
   function(callback) { getContentFromAPI("banana",callback); },
   function(callback) { doSomeProcess1(callback); },
   function(callback) { doSomeProcess2(callback); },
   function(callback) { doSomeProcess3(callback); },
   function(callback) { doSomeProcess4(callback); },
]
);
```

Is there any way this can be done better? I'm only requesting one asynchronous process and want to avoid using async since all the other processes are sync.

What should I do?

Comment: Use promises and switch from sync to async programming

Comment: you should consider using the promise api

Comment: Ajax, in Node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, since the AJAX is asynchronous, I'm forced to use async as follows

you've overcomplicated a very simple and common process ... I don't know the "signature" of whatever getContentFromAPI is, but, if it follows "standard" node callback "signature" - then your process shouldbe as simple as

```
getContentFromAPI("banana", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        // your error handling goes here
    } else {
        doSomeProcess1();
        doSomeProcess2();
        doSomeProcess3();
        doSomeProcess4();
    }
});
```